# Regression RMSE when dependent variable is log transformed

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression

I want to predict the duration a trip would take. For this I transformed my dependent variable (trip time in sec) to log transformed.

When I do regression on this variable with some other features,

I get this:

```
The score on held out data is: 0.08395386395024673
 Hyper-Parameters for Best Score : {'l1_ratio': 0.15, 'alpha': 0.01}

The R2 Score of sgd_regressor on test data is: 0.0864573982691922

The mse of sgd_regressor on test data is: 0.5503753581
The mean absolute error of sgd_regressor on test data is: 0.566328128068
```

This is the code which does the above calculation:

```
   from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, mean_absolute_error

    # 
    print("The R2 Score of "+ name + " on test data is: {}\n".format(self.g_cv.best_estimator_.score(self.test_X,self.test_Y)))

    print ("The mse of "+ name + " on test data is:",\
           mean_squared_error(test_Y, self.g_cv.best_estimator_.predict(self.test_X)))

    print ("The mean absolute error of "+ name + " on test data is:",\
           mean_absolute_error(test_Y, self.g_cv.best_estimator_.predict(self.test_X)))
```

Problem is R2 as you see is very bad. 0.08, but RMSE and Mean Absolute error seem to be very low. If I look at Mean Absolute Error, its just 0.56 sec. Which means on an average my predicted time is only half a second different from true time.

Something doesn't look right. Do I need to convert the predicted and original time variable back to linear scale from log scale before I calculate the above metrics (RMSE and MAE)?.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your metrics are being calculated on the transformed variable.

So, the MAE of 0.56 is the mean difference between the *logarithms* of the durations, not the durations themselves.

You can convert back to seconds, keeping in mind

```
log(m) - log(n) = log(m/n)
```